# Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java

I've the java class:

```
package com.server.main;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("Hello from server");
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to compile and run it. What I do is:

```
javac Main.java
```

It's OK, `Main.class` is produced.

Now, according to that **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)**, I was trying to run that program:

```
java -cp C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src\com\server\main Main
java -cp C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src\com\server\main Main.class
java -cp . Main
java -cp . Main.class
```

All these produce the output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to be three directories above where you are now, and run `java com.server.main.Main` because the name of the package is part of the name of the class.  You also need to get yourself a basic Java book or online tutorial.

Comment: @DavidWallace exactly. Tahnk you

Comment: Could you give that as an answer?

Comment: Why would I bother?  After I posted my comment, two other people posted roughly the same information as an answer.  I don't see any point in adding a third almost-identical answer.  If you want to accept an answer, pick one of the two at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Main` is in a package, I believe you need

```
java -cp C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src com.server.main.Main
```

You might also move to the top folder of your project and use `.` like

```
cd C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src
java -cp . com.server.main.Main
```

Finally, you could add that folder to your [`CLASSPATH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) like

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src
java com.server.main.Main
```

Comment: That's the core thing is to use fully-qualified class name... I haven't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer from one level above the package directory that you are using. So your package here is com.server.main which means your directory structure is:

```
src/  
    com/  
        server/  
            main/  
                Main.java  
                Main.class
```

You don't necessarily need to be at src directory (that's the reason we use -cp or -classpath option) and give the following command

Use:

```
java -cp C:\Users\workspace\Tests\src com.server.main.Main
```

Answer (score -1):

Look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

I find there answer to my problem with compile and run java application in terminal.